# Why System.IO.FileLoadException occurs in Windows application setup?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, installation

I made a windows application using c#.net(4.0) and SQLite database. It was working well while debugging, then i created the setup and installed it then when  i am executing .exe it gives the error like this:

```
  System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 
  'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without  
  additional configuration information.
```

When i was creating setup of application-

In my app.config, code is

```
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

and database was in [System.Environment.CurrentDirectory] eg. bin\debug directory, where .exe stays.

What mistake i am doing in creating the setup, do i need to add something more in the case of SQLite??

Need help!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0"/>
```